# How to export access query result to excel?

Tags: database, ms-access

In a form I create a button (Export to excel).

The code vba :

```
Private Sub Commande97_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim req As DAO.QueryDef

    Set db = CuurentDb
    Set req = db.QueryDefs("R_BC_infos")

    req.SQL = SQLListBC

    Set req = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "R_BC_infos", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "", True, "", acExportQualityPrint
End Sub
```

However when I click on the button its gives me error Object requis.

Comment: You've got a typo in that code, it's `CurrentDb`, not `CuurentDb`

Comment: yes, thanks  but it still gives me error . instruction SQL no valid: DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE

Comment: Start with basic debugging... We can't fix your code if you don't provide the necessary information. This is a SQL error, and you haven't provided the SQL.

Comment: its MS Access, the query works  i don't understand how to provided...  ?

Comment: @JamilaAmallou your Query, even in access, it has a SQL code. That's what you need to post. But looking at your code, probably it's the value of `SQLListBC`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns look at the answer to see the query

Comment: @JamilaAmallou You should have edited your question adding the code, not answer your own question

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes thank you , can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the code, i used DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method and it works

Private Sub Commande97_Click()
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "R_BC_infos", "C:\Users\reunion\Desktop\html\Classeur.xls" 'the file path
End Sub